# How to align page number in the center vertically

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using the following command to show page number in the bottom center of page:

```
% for page number at bottom center
\ohead*{}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
```

But, it appears to me that the page number is vertically aligned at TOP of the bottom margin, that takes much space of the page? How can I shift the page number down a bit (like align center) to safe space ?

Comment: \footskip is the distance from the bottom (baseline) of the text area to the baseline for the footer.  Of course, not all packages or classes follow this rule precisely.  You can set this to a larger value using geometry.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. Can you give example on how to set this. below is the geometry i am using `\geometry{
 paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
 inner=1.5in, % Inner margin
 outer=1.5in, % Outer margin
   %bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
 top=1in, % Top margin
 bottom=1in, % Bottom margin
 %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
`

Comment: bottom=1in in this case means 1in to the footer.  With nofoot or noheadfoot it means 1in to the bottom of the text area.  In either case, [footskip=...] should do the trick.